# How do I not String.Remove anything?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that may or may not need truncating. I'm passing two non-negative integers as arguments to my program. The first one is supposed to tell the program how many characters need to be removed from the beginning of the string, and the second one tells it how many characters to remove from the end. Is there a way to do it so that zeroes work properly as input, the meaning of the code is self-evident and there are no silly conditional statements like `if (removefirst != 0)`.

`string.Remove(0, removefirst)` needs the conditional statement because the first argument needs to be strictly less than the second one, says the exception message. Is there a way to do it more prettily?

Comment: Could you write the full code of this? And some sample input and expected output?

Comment: "the first argument needs to be strictly less than the second one, says the exception message" -- What's the exact exception message? Whatever it is, either it's wrong, or you're misinterpreting it. Without further info, my guess is on the latter. `"abc".Remove(2, 1)` works just fine and returns `"ab"`. `2` is definitely not less than `1`.

Comment: @hvd I was misinterpreting it. The question can safely be deleted as useless I think. Thank you for noticing; I'll flag and maybe a moderator will delete now that there's an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Math + use Substring()?

```
var result = str.Substring(firstNumber, str.Length - (firstNumber + secondNumber));
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6fO0x6)

```
string yourstring = "asdf";
string result;
int firstNumber = 0;
int secondNumber = 0;

Console.WriteLine(yourstring);
    
result = yourstring.Substring(firstNumber, yourstring.Length - (firstNumber+secondNumber));

Console.WriteLine(result);

firstNumber = 1;
secondNumber = 1;
result = yourstring.Substring(firstNumber, yourstring.Length - (firstNumber+secondNumber));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Results

> asdf
>
> asdf
>
> sd

Comment: Right you are! Thanks :)